# Access parameter name with brackets in $_POST in PHP

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I have a HTML `form` that belonged to a node.js project. In this `form` name of inputs is an array of `fields` (ie, `fields[]`) like below:

```
<form method="post" action="...">
    <label>Name</label>   
    <input type="text" name="fields[name]" required>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="fields[email]" required>
    <!-- other inputs -->
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I'm writing a `PHP` back-end for proceed this form inputs, something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    echo "name: " + $_POST['fields[name]'];
```

but when I want to access `$_POST['fields[name]']` after posting form to back-end, nothing happened, I can access whole of form data via `file_get_contents('php://input')`, But I want to access input by it's name and via `$_POST`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST);` give you?

Comment: @NigelRen, `Array ( [fields] => Array ( [name] => testname [email] => test@test.io ) ) 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using bracket on input name, give us a Two-dimensional array (2D array), in other words, we can access `<input type="text" name="fields[name]">` with this command on `PHP` back-end:

```
echo $_POST['fields']['name'];  //access value of name="fields[name]" 
echo $_POST['fields']['email']; //access value of name="fields[email]"
```